# Right side highbeam not working on on Mk2 Golf GTI - not fuse or bulb

Tags: electrical, headlight, golf, lights

I have a 93 Mk2 Golf GTI. The highbeam light on the right side of the car does not work. I have checked the fuse and bulb and both seem ok. When the head lights are not on and I toggle the passing switch neither low beam or high beam lights on the right hand side work.

Would anyone know, if not the fuse or bulb, what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure the bulb is still working? I just had a brake light bulb go out on my Touareg even though the bulb filament was still intact. Swap over the left and right side high-beam bulb and see if the circuit break follows the bulb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Bulbs - Swap the bulbs, like the comment suggested, with the ones on the other side. If works switch back and get replacement.
- Fuse - Swap the fuse with another in the fuse box with the same rating. If works switch back and get replacement.
- Connectors - Check for corrosion on connectors. Clean connectors with fine grade sand paper. Coat in something waterproof like that waterproof spray you get.
- Switch - Bypass the switch by shorting the wires, if works, switch at fault. (I take no responsibility for this.)
- Earthing (ground) - Same as connectors. Make sure earth is good. Sometimes earth is established by a screw into the body.
- Relays - Combination of fuse, connectors and switch.
- If you have a multimeter you can trace the path of the electricity and see where it drops off.
- Go to auto-electrician ;)

In your specific case, it's probably the bulb. They sometimes have two filaments one for high, and one for low. One of them may be done: the one for high.